# Проверить содержит ли ссылка фотографию C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, раньше делал так

Сначала скачивал картинку, а потом проверял содержит ли она изображение. Но когда у меня стало много картинок то время работы было... Вообщем ждал я очень долго, и в итоге результата не дождался, скачивал так

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("https://pp.userapi.com/c639318/v639318341/3beaf/PxgZctt-W_I.jpg");
client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "picture.jpg" );
```

И если ссылка не содержала изображения https://pp.userapi.com/c639318/v639318341/3beaf/PxgZctt-W_.jpg (допустим так) То мне не вылетала ошибка, оно скачивала картинку, но открыть ее нельзя было, поэтому **я задумался о проверки, есть ли по указаному адресу картинка или нет, как сделать?**

**UPD** Вопрос не про то как не получается загрузить, а в том что загрузить можно и html код в формат jpg, но это будет не картинка

Comment: Вам, собственно, что именно нужно проверять? Что по указанному URL нет файла или что по URLу именно картинка, а не что-то другое?

Comment: Хм, банальный код ответа от сервера брать, 404 - запрашиваемый объект не найдет. Не подойдет?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не подойдет, потому что банальный вариант предполагает запрос всего файла. Нужно использовать метод HEAD

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Метод HEAD может не поддерживаться или выдавать заголовки, отличные от GET.

Comment: @Squidward может и не поддерживаться. И сайт может не 404 отдать, а 200 и страничку что там ничего нет...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов А ещё мой провайдер влезает со своими рекламными страничками в любой запрос GET. Короче, что-то понадёжнее надо.

Comment: @Squidward: Я бы посоветовал в качестве технической меры противодействия бить провайдеру морду.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш вопрос ОЧЕНЬ СИЛЬНО упирается в то, что считать картинкой и насколько точное нужно определение.

А кроме того, есть два совершенно разных вопроса "не удалось загрузить" и "загрузили, но это не картинка". Вы так задали вопрос, что у некоторых складывается впечатление, что вопрос именно о том как отличить "не удалось загрузить" и поэтому предлагают закрыть вопрос как дубликат с вариантом что-то типа:

```
var document = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(url).Result;
if (document.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

Ну, если плохо сформулировали вопрос -- это в общем-то отдельная тема, а если вам нужно определять картинку или нет, то читаем дальше.

Можно пробовать определять по тому, какой в заголовке отдаёт тип контента

```
var knownImageHeaders = new[]
{
    "image/jpg",
    "image/jpeg",
    "image/x-png",
    "image/png",
};
```

Или допустим, вы решили не дожидаться скачивания всей картинки целиком, а проверять первые байты сигнатуры и на основании этого считать url "картинкой" или "не картинкой":

```
var knownFormats = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>
{
    {"jpg", new byte[] {0xFF, 0xD8}},
    {"png", new byte[] {0x89, 0x50}},
};
```

(Это ВЕСЬМА упрощённые сигнатуры, в реальности можно и более строгие проверки организовать для повышения точности - см. [например тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/678578/5752652))

Также вы можете выбрать и такой путь. Полностью грузить файл и только после того решать, это картинка или нет - и для этого просто пробуете открыть её при помощи Bitmap:

```
try
{
   var bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(...);
   // valid image stream
}
catch 
{
    // not an image
}
```

Ну а совсем не скачивая файл, даже первые несколько байт -- это весьма ненадёжный способ.

Как-то так выглядят основные пути. Какой из них выбирать -- это уже вам решать.